# Concat the two first characters of string

Tags: java, string

I have a `String s = "abcd"` and I want to make a separate `String c` that is let's say the two first characters of `String s`. I use:

```
String s = "abcd";
int i = 0;
String c = s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i+1);
System.out.println("New string is: " + c);
```

But that gives `error: incompatible types`. What should I do?

Comment: use s.substring(0,2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should concatenate two Strings and not `char`s. See [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)), it returns a `char`. So your code is equivalent to:

```
String c = 97 + 98; //ASCII values for 'a' and 'b'
```

Why? See the [JLS - 5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

You should do:

```
String c = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)) + String.valueOf(s.charAt(i+1));
```

After you've understood your problem, a better solution would be:

```
String c = s.substring(0,2)
```

More reading:

- [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)
- Worth knowing - [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Comment: ASCII is irrelevant. Java's `String`, `Character`, and `char` use Unicode/UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is

```
String c = s.substring(0, 2);
```

Now why doesn't your code work? Because you're adding two `char` values, and integer addition is used to do that. The result is thus an integer, which can't be assigned to a String variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "abcd";
```

First two characters of the String s

```
String firstTwoCharacter = s.substring(0, 2);
```

or

```
    char c[] = s.toCharArray();
    //Note that this method simply returns a call to String.valueOf(char)
    String firstTwoCharacter = Character.toString(c[0])+Character.toString(c[1]);
```

or

```
    String firstTwoCharacter = String.valueOf(c[0])+ String.valueOf(c[1]);
```